# Distinct na linq não funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Fiz essa linq em minha model:

```
public static List<MontaArvoreAcao> CriarListaArvoreAcao()
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();


              var _listaUnidade = (
                               from r in db.Ruptura
                               join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                               join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)
                               where r.IDMotivo != 6


                               select new MontaArvoreAcao
                               {
                                   Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = a.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
                                   Unidade_Negocio = a.Unidade_Negocio
                               }).ToList().Distinct();

            return _listaUnidade.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Tentando reproduzir esse selet que funciona como eu quero:

```
select distinct a.Unidade_Negocio, r.IDMotivo

from Ruptura r
join Apresentacao a on a.Codigo_Apresentacao = r.Codigo_Apresentacao
join Motivo m on r.IDMotivo = m.IDMotivo

group by r.IDMotivo,a.Unidade_Negocio

order by r.IDMotivo
```

Gostaria de saber o que fazer para funcionar? No select, com o Distinct, eu trago apenas 17 registros, já na linq eu trago mais de 3 mil. Só preciso trazer uma UN para cada motivo, conforme está na query(select).

Fiz assim e não repetiu mais os caras, mas ainda não vem o resultado correto.

```
public static List<MontaArvoreAcao> CriarListaArvoreAcao()
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

              var _listaUnidade = (
                                       from r in db.Ruptura
                                       join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                                       join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)
                                       where r.IDMotivo != 6

                                       select new MontaArvoreAcao
                                       {
                                           Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = a.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
                                           Unidade_Negocio = a.Unidade_Negocio,
                                           IDMotivo = r.IDMotivo
                                       }

                                  ).ToList().Distinct().DistinctBy(s => s.IDMotivo).DistinctBy(d => d.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio);

            return _listaUnidade.ToList();
        }
```

Aí um colega em outro site me falou e sugeriu isso:
Vc esta usando de forma errada, o DistinctBy serve para pegar todos os itens qua aquela propriedade for 1 por exemplo...

então vc esta filtrando todos  (SEM REPETIR) codigo unidade negocio .DistinctBy(d => d.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio)

e em seguida vc esta filtrando todos (SEM REPETIR) IDMOTIVO DistinctBy(s => s.IDMotivo); então vai existir somente um ID MOTIVO de cada...

No seu caso como vc precisa comparar se o objeto LEVANDO EM CONTA AS 2 PROPRIEDADES, implementa o  Object.Equals() and Object.GetHashCode()  na classe MontaArvoreAcao

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (!(obj is MontaArvoreAcao)) return false;

                MontaArvoreAcao p = (MontaArvoreAcao)obj;
                return Codigo_Unidade_Negocio == p.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio & IDMotivo == p.IDMotivo;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return Codigo_Unidade_Negocio ^ IDMotivo;
            }
```

E use apenas Distinct como estava antes, agora ele vai saber comparar se os objetos são iguais (Codigo Unidade Negocio e IDMOTIVO).

Mas nessa linha dá o erro:

```
return Codigo_Unidade_Negocio ^ IDMotivo;
```

Ele diz que o operando ^ não pode ser usado em tipo string e int.

Está dando erro no meu GroupBy. Veja como eu fiz:

```
......).GroupBy(g => new { g.IDMotivo, g.Unidade_Negocio }).DistinctBy(d => d.Unidade_Negocio).DistinctBy(s => s.IDMotivo)
```

O erro diz que  `d.Unidade_Negocio`, que não contem uma definição para ele.

Cheguei a conclusão que esse group não vai servir de nada. Não entendo o seguinte. Tentei fazer a LINQ igual a QUERY que roda no banco. Comparando tudo, parece que a linq é um espelho da minha query. A query me trás o resultado correto e a linq não. Por exemplo. Eu tenho 5 Motivos, com os seguintes ID's. 1,2,3,4 e 5. No Motivo de ID=1, eu tenho essas UN's: DERMOCOSMÉTICOS, GENÉRICOS E MIP.  No Motivo ID=2, eu tenho: DERMOCOSMÉTICOS, GENÉRICOS E MIP. E assim para o ID=3 e ID=5. Porém no ID=4, eu tenho apenas: DERMOCOSMÉTICOS e GENÉRICOS. Quando eu rodo a LINQ e monto na minha View, aparece em baixo de cada motivo o seguinte: MIP e GENÉRICOS. Isso para todos os motivos e isso não está correto. Olho para a LINQ e não consigo ver nada. Não sei o que pode estar errado.  Essa é a model atual mas o que você me sugeriu que eu fizesse:

```
public static List<MontaArvoreAcao> CriarListaArvoreAcao()
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            var _listaUnidade = (
                                     from r in db.Ruptura
                                     join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                                     join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)

                                     where r.IDMotivo != 6

                                     select new MontaArvoreAcao
                                     {
                                         Unidade_Negocio = a.Unidade_Negocio,
                                         IDMotivo = r.IDMotivo
                                     }

                                ).DistinctBy(d => d.Unidade_Negocio).DistinctBy(s => s.IDMotivo).OrderBy(r => r.IDMotivo);

            return _listaUnidade.ToList();
        }
```

Cara, tá osso isso aqui. E já me pediram mais coisas, e... bem, tá osso e preciso desossar essa bagaça. Qualquer ajuda, caminho, oração é bem-vindo.

Comment: pnet, você tentou dar o distinct antes de executar o primeiro .ToList() ?

Answer (score 4):

Não é assim que usa o `Distinct()`. O `Distinct()` filtra apenas objetos idênticos, o que não é o caso da sua consulta.

Utilize o método [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) do pacote NuGet MoreLinq:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/1.1.0

Uso:

```
return _listaUnidade.DistinctBy(l => l.IDMotivo).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Diz [a documentação do Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Retorna os elementos distintos de uma seqüência usando o comparador de igualdade padrão para comparar valores.

Ênfase em `comparador de igualdade padrão`.

A comparação padrão de igualdade para tipos anônimos é a comparação de referência. Como cada um dos mais de três mil elementos tem um endereço diferente na memória, a comparação entre dois elementos quaisquer sempre vai indicar que são diferentes. Mesmo que os dados sejam os mesmos.

Para resolver isso, crie seu próprio tipo de dados para armazenar essas informações - e sobrecarregue o método [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) para comparar os dados ao invés das referências.

Ou você pode fazer como sugeriu o Vinícius e executar o método `distinct` antes de transformar os dados do banco em elementos de uma lista ;)